# I am getting an Error Message when i try to play a specific Animation Clip

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make the Enemy Play an animation on trigger collision but I am getting the error message below.

```
Assets\Scripts\you.cs(49,18): error CS1501: No overload for method 'Play' takes 3 arguments
```

My code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class you : MonoBehaviour
{
    public const float InitialSpeed = 0.5f;
    public bool isDead = false;
    public float upForce = 100f;
    public LayerMask ground;
    private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    public float speed = InitialSpeed;
    public bool isgrounded = false;
    public float checkradius = 0.5f;
    public GameObject groundcheck;
    public float translation;
    public Animation anim;

void Start()
{
    rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
}

void Update()
{

    transform.Translate(translation, 0, 0);
    isgrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(transform.position, checkradius, ground);
    translation = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * InitialSpeed;


    if (isDead == false)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {
            rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            rb2d.AddForce(new Vector2(0, upForce));
        }
    }
}


void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
    {
        anim.Play("Enemydie", 0, 0f);
        Debug.Log(other.gameObject.name);
        Destroy(other.gameObject, 0.1f);
    }
}
}
```

Maybe someone could help I've looked through other posts but can't seem to find one that fixes my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Animation.Play](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.Play.html) only takes 2 arguments, 1 of which is optional.

> public bool Play(PlayMode mode = PlayMode.StopSameLayer); 
>   public bool Play(string animation, PlayMode mode = PlayMode.StopSameLayer);

If you are indeed using an `Animation` component and not an [Animator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.Play.html) which takes 3 arguments, then you can update to:

```
anim.Play("Enemydie");
```

I assume you are indeed using an `Animation` component as you would be getting a null ref exception when trying to call `Play()`